# convert columns to rows based on row value using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel file as follows:

```
ID      wk48     wk49    wk50    wk51   wk52   wk1   wk2 
1123     10        22      233     2     4     22     11
1198      9         4       44    23    34     5     234
101       3         6        3    43    33     34     78
```

I want the output as follows in python

```
1123 wk48  10
1123 wk49  22
1123 wk50  233
1123 wk51  2
1123 wk52  4
1123 wk1   22
1123 wk2   11
1198 wk48  9
1198 wk49  4
1198 wk50  44
1198 wk51  23
1198 wk52  34
1198 wk1   5
1198 wk2   234
```

Any suggestions

Comment: You're going to get downvoted (or even have your question closed) because this doesn't meet the stack overflow guidelines: what have you tried? Please provide a sample of code showing your efforts

Comment: This would be a reasonable question if you explained exactly what you want to do, and if you made it clear what parts of your desired output are supposed to be columns, and which are supposed to be the index.

Comment: Input is (Input.xlsx)

col1 col2 cole3 ID      wk48     wk49    wk50    wk51   wk52   wk1   wk2 
asdf 123 7ds3 1123     10        22      233     2     4     22     11
uerr 4dd 3de34 1198      9         4       44    23    34     5     234

Ouput needed is (output.csv)

asdf 123 7ds3 1123  wk48   10
asdf 123 7ds3 1123  wk49   22
asdf 123 7ds3 1123  wk50   233
asdf 123 7ds3 1123  wk51   2
asdf 123 7ds3 1123  wk52   4
asdf 123 7ds3 1123  wk1    22
asdf 123 7ds3 1123  wk2    11
uerr 4dd 3de34 1198  wk48   9
uerr 4dd 3de34 1198  wk49   4
......

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I would do is set `ID` as your index with:

```
df.set_index('ID',inplace=True)
```

Next, you can use the following command to reorient your dataframe:

```
df = df.stack().reset_index()
print df
-------------------------------------------
Output:
      ID level_1    0
0   1123    wk48   10
1   1123    wk49   22
2   1123    wk50  233
3   1123    wk51    2
4   1123    wk52    4
5   1123     wk1   22
6   1123     wk2   11
7   1198    wk48    9
8   1198    wk49    4
9   1198    wk50   44
10  1198    wk51   23
11  1198    wk52   34
12  1198     wk1    5
13  1198     wk2  234
14   101    wk48    3
15   101    wk49    6
16   101    wk50    3
17   101    wk51   43
18   101    wk52   33
19   101     wk1   34
20   101     wk2   78
```

Comment: Thanks for the details Michael.. I have used pd.melt command  like 
pd.melt(df, id_vars = ["Name"], var_name = "Wk") 
after this i did a sort and then saved to a csv file ..is that also works ?

Answer (score 1):

Read the data in pandas:

```
In[1]:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('yourfile.xlsx', index_col=0)
```

Then use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to move the columns to the index:

```
In [2]: s = df.stack()
        # Rename the index names for cleaner output
        s.index.names = ['ID','Week']
```

You'll get a pd.Series like you want:

```
In [3]: s.head(10)
Out[3]: 
ID    Week    
1123  wk48     10
      wk49     22
      wk50    233
      wk51      2
      wk52      4
      wk1      22
      wk2      11
1198  wk48      9
      wk49      4
      wk50     44
dtype: int64
```

In case you want that back as a dataframe:

```
In [4]: s.name = 'Value'
        df = s.to_frame()
```

You can then export that back to Excel for example:

```
In [5]: df.to_excel('newfile.xslx')
```

Or if you don't like to have `ID` being grouped (merged cells) in excel, you can do this:

```
In [6]: df.reset_index().to_excel('newfile.xlsx', index=False)
```